# PHP Static Class Auto Reset

Tags: php, class, static

I'm writing a class that I plan to only call statically and I noticed something I wasn't expecting. Consider the following code.

```
<?php
class Greeting {
  public static $greetingMSG;

  public static function setGreeting(string $greeting){
    self::$greetingMSG = $greeting;
    return new static;
  }

  public static function greet() {
    echo self::$greetingMSG;
  }
}

Greeting::greet();

Greeting::setGreeting('Hello World!')->greet();

Greeting::greet();

?>
```

I would have thought that the first and third call to `Greeting::greet();` would have given the same result. Instead, the second and third call gives the same result. I understand that must be because each call to the class `Greeting` is not creating a new instance of the class. I could make the class mimic what I was expecting by adding a `reset()` method.

```
<?php
class Greeting {
  public static $greetingMSG;

  public static function setGreeting(string $greeting){
    self::$greetingMSG = $greeting;
    return new static;
  }

  public static function greet() {
    echo self::$greetingMSG;
    self::reset();
  }

  private static function reset() {
    self::$greetingMSG = '';
  }
}

Greeting::greet();

Greeting::setGreeting('Hello World!')->greet();

Greeting::greet();

?>
```

This behaves like I was expecting and "Hello World!" is only output once. Is there a more technical explanation as to what is going on here and is the `reset()` method the best way to mimic what I was expecting?

Comment: Minor note, PHP coding standards state that class names should be in `PascalCase` not lower case.

Comment: @BadHorsie Normally I do use `PascalCase` for class names. In my haste to create an example class I must have missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that must be because each call to the class `greeting` is not creating a new instance of the class

I think you have a basic misunderstanding about some fundamentals here.

This has nothing to do with whether `$greetingMSG` is static or not. Once you set a class member variable, its value will remain the same until you change it. All subsequent calls to echo the variable will just keep echoing the value you already set that one time previously. This would behave the same whether it was static or not.

Yes, you could have a reset method which clears the value if you want to, and you're really just doing the same job as `setGreeting('');`.

In any case, I'm not sure what the purpose of this class being full of static methods is in the first place, or why you would have a private reset method. In my opinion, this is not a well designed class.

Why not just a normal class without the static methods? It would be more flexible and makes more sense. Here is an example of a bunch of usages:

```
$greeting = new Greeting('Hello World!');
$greeting->greet();

$greeting->setMessage('Goodbye World!');
$greeting->greet();
$greeting->greet();

$greeting2 = new Greeting();
$greeting2->setMessage('Finished');
$greeting2->greet();

$greeting->greet();
```

This prints, in this order:

```
Hello World!
Goodbye World!
Goodbye World!
Finished
Goodbye World!
```

Some things to note about this:

1. You can have multiple greeting instances this way, with different messages.
2. We can infer from my code that the `Greeting` class has a constructor which allows you to set the message when you create the instance, or you can create a blank one and set the message later with `setMessage()`.
3. To show my point about how a variable's value stays the same until you alter it, note that after we create a second `Greeting` instance, echoing the message of the first `Greeting` object still gives the same value it had before, because it still has not been changed.

Comment: I probably am missing some fundamentals, but this example greetings class doesn't really convey what I'm trying to achieve. I'm actually trying to build a static data access class so that I can query for data like `$qResult = Data::table('something')->select('column1')->where('column2', '=', 'somevalue');`. Where my confusion came in is later when I was trying to run a query with no where clause It was still being filtered with the previous where clause because I was storing the where clause in a static property. My impression was that each time I used `Data` its properties would be reset.

Comment: @MatthewGoheen I see. Well no, if you want to reset properties you have to reset them yourself somehow, whether it's static or not.

Answer (score 0):

The $greetingMSG property is static, wich means that its contents is shared with all the instances of greeting class. Lets go through steps:

First step:

```
greeting::greet();
```

This will output an empty string, right? Beucase the $greetingMSG value's is not defined yet.

Second step:

```
greeting::setGreeting('Hello World!')->greet();
```

In this step, you define a value to the $greetingMSG static property, prints it and the define an empty string as its value again. That said, the output will be 'Hello, World!'.

Third step:

```
greeting::greet();
```

Finally, this will output an empty string again, because you just defined that $greetingMSG is a empty string again.